# Копия свойств массива в новый массив JS

Tags: javascript

С помощью прототипов нужно скопировать значения массива и продублировать их в новый массив.
То есть, имеется
`[1,2]`
нужно, чтобы
`[1,2].ocopy()`
вернул результат [1,2,1,2].

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var co = function() {
    var nor = [], count = Object.keys(this).length;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        nor.push(this[i]);
        nor.push(this[i]);
    }
    return nor;
  }
  Object.prototype.ocopy = co();
  console.log([1,2].ocopy());
</script>
```

В таком виде код совсем не работает, а this в функции co() вообще понимает, что обращаемся к window.

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Ваш вариант решения и не должен работать. Даже если забыть про `this` он не имеет ничего общего с копированием элементов.

Comment: это да, часть копирования не написал пока, ибо смысла нет, потому что this не берет то, что нужно

Comment: `Object.prototype.ocopy = co();` - вы присваиваете результат выполнения функции, т.е. `count`, а не саму функцию.

Comment: `[1,2].ocopy()` должна вернуть 2, а возвращает '[1,2].ocopy is not a function'

Comment: @Sh.Khachatryan а почему он должен вернуть `2`?! по условиям задачи он должен вернуть `[1,2,1,2]`. Вы бы для начала определились, что именно вам нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для Ваших целей подойдет встроенная функция `Array.prototype.concat()`, она принимает, как аргументы, n массивов, которые надо слить в один.

```
Array.prototype.ocopy = function() {
    var newArray = [];
    newArray = newArray.concat(this, this)
    return newArray;
};
```

Лаконичней это будет выглядеть так:

```
Array.prototype.ocopy = function() {
    return [].concat(this, this);
};
```

Ваша ошибка состоит в том, что вы присваиваете методу объекта уже результат функии, а не саму функцию. То есть надо бы сделать так: `Object.prototype.ocopy = co;`

P.S. Замечу, что править прототипы существующих типов считается не очень хорошим тоном. Слишком глобальное это действие и надо следить, чтобы в будущем это не привело к неясностям.

Comment: `return [].concat(this, this);` смотрится нагляднее :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, задача была показать наглядность для человека, который не искушен такими конструкциями. Думаю хороший минификатор сделал бы это за человека.